# Associating a new version of SSMS with .sql file extension

Tags: windows-7, file-association

Originally, the .sql file extension was associated with notepad.

I changed this by right-clicking on a .sql file and choosing "Open With" -> "Choose Default Program" to associate it with SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) 2008R2. This worked fine.

Now SQL Server 2012 is out, I've tried to re-associate the .sql extension with SSMS 2012 using the same right-click method, however the new association never sticks, it continues to use SSMS 2008R2.
Any ideas on how to get it to remember the new version of SSMS?

I'm using Windows 7 Pro x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [File Types Manager from Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) to change the Edit and Open actions (including the double-click) from SSMS 2008R2 to SSMS 2012.
Everything works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me by editing PATH variable. I changed it such that sql 2012 (110) comes first in PATH variable as below:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;

after that when I reassociated the sql file with ssms 2012 it worked

Answer (score -1):

I used TotalCommander for this, see picture. Now all *.sql scripts open for me in SSMS19, including DDE, and the script icon has also changed to a new look. I have SSMS2014 SSMS19 installed concurrently (Windows 10 x64).